# MVC design pattern with swings

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC design pattern.

I am developing a GUI application with java Swings, i have few basic questions.

In my scenario there will be one main page with menu options, on click on menu option I should load some other page and that page will have some different events (this page also should contain the main menu).

now my requirement is I want each page should have its own model,view and controller. But how can those pages will interact each other? main page events should be available to all other pages.

Give some guidelines to follow with small example if you have anything.

Comment: [Go through this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html)

Comment: I read it but it is not that clear to follow

Answer (score 1):

Your GUI should have one model class for the whole GUI.  You can have subordinate model classes, depending on how the model is defined.

Your GUI should have as many view classes as you need to define the GUI (generally, one per JPanel), and as many controller classes as you need with each controller class handling one event.

The model / view / controller pattern in Swing is generally defined in the following way.

1. The view may read values from the model.
2. The view **may not update** the model.
3. The controller will update the model.
4. The controller will repaint the view.

Take a look at my article, [Java Swing Marquee](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=681), to see how you would code model classes, view classes, and controller classes.